# Network interface connected but could not connect internet

Tags: hyper-v

I've installed SCientific Linux 7.1 x64 as guest on windows 10 x64's hyper-v.

The problem is network connected, but could not connect internet and browse web page as shown in the attached photo.

[image]

Any helpful comments would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the VM have valid ip settings?

Comment: It could be a route problem.... What do you get when you type > ip route or > route print

Comment: The result s here::

[root@localhost -]# ip route
default via 192.168.G.1 dev ethG proto static metric 1G0
192.168.0.0/24 dev ethO proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.4 metric 100

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping something like:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

If yes, then your problem is with `/etc/resolv.conf` not being properly setup. In that case I would check your distribution's guidelines to fix this.  As sample `/etc/resolv.conf` that can work may contain the following line only:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: I added "nameserver 8.8.8.8", but the result of "ping 8.8.8.8" is this::

'[root@locaihost -]# ping 8.8.8.8 
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data
From 192.168.0.4 icmp_seq=l Destination Unreachable'

Comment: After changing 'nameserver 8.8.8.8', I reboot vm, then browsed 'google.com'. Thanks a lot!